# How to merge two tables data in one using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

Table #1: `tbl_test1`

```
id | product1 | price1|
---+----------+-------+
1  | A        | 200   |
2  | B        | 250   |
3  | C        | 300   |
```

Table #2 : `tbl_test2`

```
id | product2 | price2|
---+----------+-------+
40 | P        | 200   |
20 | Q        | 250   |
```

and I want to result in my given format

```
id | product1 | price1|id | product2 | price2|
---+----------+-------+---+----------+-------+
1  | A        | 200   |50 | P        | 200   |
2  | B        | 250   |40 | Q        | 250   |
3  | C        | 300   |   |          |       |
```

Please help...

Comment: What is the relation of the two tables, also why in the resul for the second table we have the id 50 and 40 and in the table2 we have id 40, 20.

Comment: THERE IS NO RELATION

Comment: @Ravi Kumar, How come the id's for P & Q are different in tbl_test2 and your expected result?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what's your end game but if you just want to display your data side by side you need to use `FULL JOIN`. Additionally, you have to add a `ROW_NUMBER` for each of your tables:

```
WITH CteTest1 AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)
    FROM #tbl_test1
),
CteTest2 AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)
    FROM #tbl_test2
)
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.product1, t1.price1,
    t2.id, t2.product2, t2.price2
FROM CteTest1 t1
FULL JOIN CteTest2 t2
    ON t2.rn = t1.rn
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503111)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @FirstTable table (StudentId int, SubjectId int)
declare @SecondTable table (MarksId int, RankId int, LastRank int)

insert into @FirstTable values (1, 1)
insert into @FirstTable values (1, 2)
insert into @FirstTable values (1, 3)

insert into @SecondTable values (1, 4, 10)
insert into @SecondTable values (1, 5, 11)

;with XmlTable (RowNumber, StudentId, SubjectId) as
(
    select row_number() over(order by StudentId) as RowNumber, * from @FirstTable
)
,TechnicalIdsTable (RowNumber, MarksId, RankId, LastRank) as
(
    select row_number() over(order by MarksId) as RowNumber, * from @SecondTable
)
select x.StudentId, x.SubjectId, t.MarksId, t.RankId, t.LastRank from XmlTable x 
left join TechnicalIdsTable t
on x.RowNumber = t.RowNumber
```